# Where are the display settings for the virtual desktop layout in Windows 10 stored/saved?

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

[Display Settings dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RgP5.png)

Specifically, the actual coordinates for the layout pictured below.  I assume somewhere in the registry but have not been able to locate any information on that!

Thanks for any help!